# multiple (redundant?) observeValueForKeyPath: messages received

Tags: cocoa, key-value-observing

I have an obj-C Mac app with an object observing some property (bool) of `standardUserDefaults`.

The code is pretty standard:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"property" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

This `standardUserDefaults`' `property` is bound to an `NSButton` state.

When I click the button, the property changes as normal, but up to 8 messages in a row notifying a change in the property are received at each click! I have no idea why that is. The property is not bound to anything else but the button. I checked that the button is indeed clicked once. The value of the `property` is the same across notifications resulting from the same click.
This also occurs without binding if I manually change the property via

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"property"];
```

After that, 8 `observeValueForKeyPath:` messages are received in a row!

The only related issue I found was this one: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/47609.

Any idea?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is the button in the same app? How is the button configured (push, checkbox, radio, …)? How can we reproduce the issue?

Comment: Same App. To reproduce, have a toggle button whose `value` is bound (in interface builder) to an Standard User Default property (bool), and have an `NSObject` subclass observe that property (see sample code above). Override `observeValueForKeyPath: ofObject:change: context:` in that subclass to receive KVO notifications. In that method, add `if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"property"]) NSLog(@"received")`. And count the number of message arriving in the console at each click.

Comment: `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` is called once for each click in my test app. What is a toggle button? When and how many times do you call `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`?

Comment: Thanks for testing. I think I found the error. I was calling `addObserver:` in `awakeFromNib` and the latter is called many times since the observer is the owner of NSTableView cell views (which call `awakeFromNib:` on their owner each time they are created). So the same object was registered many time as an observer of the same keypath. I'm not sure in which method I should call `addObserver:` to avoid that. This observer object is just an `NSObject` subclass that I added to the xib.

Comment: Which object is `self`?

Comment: It is an `NSObject` subclass that is the delegate of a view-based `NSTableView` and the owner of the view's cell and row views. `awakeFromNib:` is called on this object each time a view cell is created (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1535482-makeviewwithidentifier?language=objc)

Comment: Add the observer in the `init` method.

Comment: This works. But since I need to do other things in `awakeFromNib` that I cannot do in `init` anyway (like setting the menu for the table header view), I added a control to avoid repeating things unnecessarily.